# 3D rotation tool. How can I add simple extrusion?

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

The 3D rotation tool is excellent but it only lets you rotate 2D objects, this means my object is wafer thin.

Is there any way to add simple extrusion or depth to a symbol?

I don't really want to use any 3rd party libraries like Away3D or Papervision, this is overkill for my simple 2D game. I only want to do this creating a couple motion tweens if possible.

**More Details:**

Below is what my symbol looks like (just with a bit more color). The symbol does a little 3D rotation and then flies away, it's just for something like a scoreboard within the app.

[image]

Comment: A "fake" method can be copying 10-15 copies of that movieclip one after another by code. However not useful, if you are going to make further 3d modifications on it.

Comment: @VishwasGagrani: Thanks, I tried this earlier. It works fine on the PC, but on iOS or android it's a slow and bumpy ride.

Comment: Simple answer is: yes, there are ways to add extrusion to a symbol. Whether there are easy ways depend a lot on what you mean by "a symbol", or what kind of object you have. Turning a square into a cube is easy, turning a mandelbrot into a heightfield is harder.

Comment: @JariKomppa: My symbol is just 2 rectangles joined together, the rectangles both have rounded corners. Please share any tips you have.

Comment: @JariKomppa: I've just posted an update with pic.

Comment: The rounded corners might pose some problems (depending on how round you want the result to be), but basic idea is to find the border vertices, border edges, and just construct the extruded side polygons.

Answer (score 1):

For all that you don't want to use 3rd Party 3D frameworks, a simple solution for the rounded corners won't be that simple.

@Jari Komppa - his approach is the way to do it, but you'll spend some time making all the corner pieces.  Each corner will probably need 3 polygons to replicate the curve satisfactorily. So you'd have to add 15 polygons for the rounded edges and another 7 for the other side and back faces. If that works for you, have at it.  The nice thing about something like Away3D is that you can import a 3ds or other model and use that instead.  No trying to work out the intricacies of 3D model in code.

Comment: Also, depending on how you rotate the item, you might only need half the polygons.  Do you have an example of the rotation?